# Can gatsby static query using filter?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Can static query using filter?

im using strapi as my config server

i will gather the config data on build time

And i have a component which need to query the config data by user data (e.g user group)

however it seem gatsby not allow me to pass any var to the query or even hard code the query with the param

e.g

```
graphql`
query MyQuery {
allStrapiAvailableLanguageByMarkets(filter: {country: {code: {eq: "CA"}}}) {
nodes {
country {
code
}
languages {
code
name
}
}
}
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

StaticQuery has it's own limitations (that's why it's are called static) and they do not allow any dynamic parameter. As it shows [Gatsby documention](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/):

> **How StaticQuery differs from page query**
>
> StaticQuery can do most of the
> things that page query can, including fragments. The main differences
> are:
>
> - page queries can accept variables (via pageContext) but can only be
>   added to page components
> - `StaticQuery` does not accept variables (hence
>   the name “static”), but can be used in any component, including pages
> - StaticQuery does not work with raw React.createElement calls; please
>   use JSX, e.g.

Of course, you can filter using a hardcoded value, this is actually the only solution available for you can't filter using a dynamic value.

Check your `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to see if your query works (it should). Usually chained values in GraphQL must be filtered using `filter: { country__code: { eq:"CA" }}`

Ideally, your `useStaticQuery` hook file should look like:

```
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby';

export const useYourItems = () => {
  const yourItems  = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
        query MyQuery {
            allStrapiAvailableLanguageByMarkets(filter: {country: {code: {eq: "CA"}}}) {
                nodes {
                    country {
                        code
                    }
                    languages {
                        code
                        name
                    }
                }
            }
        }`,
  );

  return yourItems.allStrapiAvailableLanguageByMarkets;
};
```

Then, in another component:

```
  const yourItems = useYourItems();
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, i have read this too, but turn on it doesnt allow filter... even hardcode

Comment: Does your query works in the playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`)? You can add automatically filters there. Did you checked `filter: { country__code: { eq:"CA" }}`?

Comment: it work in playground, but if use this static query in reactjs component -> it said ×
Error: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched.

This is likely a bug in Gatsby and if refreshing the page does not fix it, please open an issue in https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are using the `staticQuery`?

Comment: i put it into a very simple component inside the layout.js

Comment: e.g const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query MyQuery {
            allStrapiAvailableLanguageByMarkets(filter: {country: {code: {eq: "CA"}}}) {
                nodes {
                    languages {
                    code
                    name
                    }
                    country {
                    code
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `);

Comment: In your question please, it's difficult to look at it in a comment.

Comment: sure, i just realize that the query work if i do it like that : useStaticQuery(graphql`xxxxxxx`), it wont work if i do it like that : useStaticQuery(JS_VAR)

Comment: if it is the case, it mean i cant put the query into a js file, then export it for re use purpose

Comment: You can reuse your `useStaticQuery` of course. I've provided an example using your query.

Comment: awesome thx, but put the whole useStaticQuery into a function? will it break the rule of using hook

Comment: It's not a nested function so it won't break the rule. If you look at the usage of `useStaticQuery` by Gatsby's official documentation they provide a similar usage. In the end, a hook is a function. In addition, it allows you to reuse it as many times as you wish in different components. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217776/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-user192344).